# When one dropdown is selected then the same option is selected in a different dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two dropdowns and I want to make it whenever someone selects something in one dropdown the same thing is selected in the other dropdown. I can't get it to work when I select an option in the first dropdown then it doesn't select the same option in the other dropdown.
Here's the formula

```
$( function() {
    $("input[name='FirstFlangeTypeDrop']").on("change", function(e) {
         var newValue = e.target.value;
         $("input[name='SecondFlangeTypeDrop'][value='" + newValue + "']").prop("selected", true);
      });
    });
```

Comment: So what is the problem you are having? You have told us what you want/expect but you haven't explain the issue. Also this is using `jQuery` so be sure to load the library and you might want to update your question and add the `jQuery` tag.

Comment: I can't get it to work when I select an option in the first dropdown then it doesn't select the same option in the other dropdown.

Comment: Are the select elements exactly the same?

Comment: make this a working snippet of what you have

Comment: Both Elements have the exact same value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear to me. But I think this is what you are looking for.

```js
$(function() {

  $("select[name='FirstFlangeTypeDrop']").on("change", function(e) {
    var newValue = $(this).val(); // get selected value
    $("select[name='SecondFlangeTypeDrop']").val(newValue); // set selected value
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="FirstFlangeTypeDrop">
<option value="1">option 1</option>
<option value="2">option 2</option>
</select>

<select name="SecondFlangeTypeDrop">
<option value="1">option 1</option>
<option value="2">option 2</option>
</select>
```